# SharePoint REST API to create child term under a Parent Term

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, taxonomy

Through PowerAutomate I am calling SharePoint Rest API to create Terms.

I am able to create term under termset with below API and Body.
Url: `_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/@{variables('GroupId')}/sets/@{variables('TermSetId')}/children`

```
{  
    "labels": [  
        {  
            "name": "@{triggerBody()?['Title']}",  
            "isDefault": true,  
            "languageTag": "en-US"  
        }  
    ],  
    "descriptions": [  
        {  
            "description": "@{triggerBody()?['Title']}",  
            "languageTag": "en-US"  
        }  
    ]  
}
```

Now I want to create a child term under particular term, May I know how to pass parent term id in the request body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide `Parent Term Id` in URL itself as below:

```
/sites/{site-id}/termStore/sets/{set-id}/terms/{term-id}/children
```

Or

```
/sites/{site-id}/termStore/groups/{group-id}/sets/{set-id}/terms/{term-id}/children
```

By the way, you don't require `Term Group Id` to add `Term` into `TermSet`. Only `TermSet Id` will enough for this.

[image]

[image]

See Official Documentation at below:

[Create term](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/termstore-term-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)